# Odoo and python program

Tags: odoo-10

In HR module, in Employee form, I want to create a filter which gives me list of all employees birthdays current month in odoo 10.How to create the filter employees current month birthdays list

Comment: i want display current month birthdays list.but i wrote the current month list.but not other year.for example bhanu date of birth :1/5/2017                                    hemanth date of birth is :2/5/2017        and kishore date of birth is : 3/5/1995 , here i displayed the only two names hemanth and bhanu,kishore name did not come because it will take only this year(2017). so please tell me this month and any year employee birthday list through domain and filters in odoo10

Comment: <filter string="Current month Employee Birthday list" domain="[('birthday','&lt;=',(context_today()+relativedelta(day=31)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('birthday','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(day=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"/>